# Need to find out Passport from the image using EMGUCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a requirement to find out the passport and its details from the give image using Emgu.CV.

Can somebody help me to give direction regarding how to start with this. If somebody can show me the steps or ways to go for the solution would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Parthiv

Comment: what kind of images ? can you upload an example?

Comment: I would say you have to show us what you've tried thus far in order for us to help you. Otherwise this will be a to broad question or we would have to find libraries and examples for you. We're not here to do your research, we're here to help you with a particular error or faulty logic in your code or regarding your coding tools such as your IDE. We're not here to code everything for you - even tho it might just be a nudge in a direction. There's examples and guides on Emgu:CV, i suggest you start off there.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your response guys. you can find out the actual image here sorry have to blur out stuff on the image <br/>https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hg8hoqitvwzysn/pass1.bmp?dl=0  <br/> I have tried out the sample of emgu.cv. but I could not make it work. I tried with the shapes but that also do not work. I have gone through the documentation of emgu. <br/> ofcourse I am not askign for readymade code or somebody do the code for me. what I am asking is, from where I should start looking. I have not done any work in image processing, so aksing for direction and then I will work it out. Thanks